# Use TextEdit's AutoCorrect everywhere (especially in Google Chrome)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, auto-complete

I really love typing in TextEdit. It seems to correct all my typos and so saves time in editing.

Is there anyway I can get this functionality to work in all applications, especially on Google Chrome's text fields.

I've searched everywhere, but I can only find articles about Chrome's own built in Auto Correct (which isn't available on the Mac yet).

<sup>OS X 10.9</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TextEdit's autocorrect is actually **OS X's autocorrect**, which is used in every system text box in the OS, in every application, including 3rd-party applications.

The problem comes when apps use their *own* text boxes—they then have to implement [NSSpellChecker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpellChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) themselves. Whilst the [Google Chrome issue relating to this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90278) seems to suggest that nothing has changed, my limited testing seems to suggest that it has been implemented in Canary.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in Canary. But at least there is an issue raised, so I guess the only option is to wait....